# Are nested span tags OK in XHTML?

Tags: html, xhtml

Will this validate in XHTML?

```
<span>hello<span>world</span></span>
```

Comment: I wonder how this question managed to collect hundreds of upvotes over the years.

Comment: @MrLister I guess because I have just googled the question and this article showed up ... :)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Yes it will. You can help yourself by using the [w3's validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) direct input option:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
        <head>
          <title>Title</title>
        </head>

        <body>
           <p>
               <span>Test<span>Nest span</span></span>
           </p>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: That will answer the "validate" part of the question, but not the "OK" part. The DTD can only describe a subset of the specification.

Answer (score 89):

Absolutely.

Here's the definition from an XHTML-strict DOCTYPE for a span element.

```
<!ELEMENT span %Inline;> <!-- generic language/style container -->
<!ATTLIST span
  %attrs;
  >
```

The "%Inline" part tells me that it can have child nodes from the "% Inline;" entities element list.

The span element is included in the list of elements classed as "% Inline", that combined with span allowing "%Inline" child elements tells me that span is a valid child of span.

Answer (score 30):

SPAN can contain only inline elements, such as SPAN etc.

Comment: Span will do what I tell it to! `span { display:block }` :D

Comment: Well, it still can not contain block level elements, even if you make it styled as a block. BTW, check also that my answer was posted 8 years back.

Comment: I know was just trying to create lol...and yes you "can" put block elements inside spans its not like the browser will explode or anything ...but its some you shouldn't do as a rule of thumb to follow proper web standards thats all.

Comment: That's point. Thanks to the web standards you don't have to hack your way through the web anymore. Jokes aside, I am thankful that we have them.

Comment: I get a Validation error from having an H tag nested within a span. Everything functions correctly. Do I Need to change it?

Comment: Yes, put H out of span and span inside H.