# HTML span tag question

Tags: html

I was wondering can I wrap a span tag around multiple a tags and another span tag?

Here is the Html code.

```
<span>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
</span>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are nested span tags OK in XHTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078127/are-nested-span-tags-ok-in-xhtml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. That is valid html :) You can check with [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate%5Fby%5Finput).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible since both `span` and `a` are inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

yes you are allowed to if you have any doubts you can just validate on [w3c input validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate%5Fby%5Finput)
very good tool!