# How do I prevent my anchor tag from line-through?

Tags: html

I have my span tag:

```
<span style="text-decoration:line-through" > Hello World <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a> </span>
```

As you can see I have applied line-through on span. But this  results in line-through on anchor tag too. How do I prevent line-through on anchor tag. I don't want strike on my anchor tag.

**Note:** Please don't ask me to move my anchor tag outside of span tag! If I could do that I wouldn't be asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From  [CSS text-decoration property cannot be overridden by child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481318/css-text-decoration-property-cannot-be-overridden-by-child-element) ]

[text-decoration specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props) state:

> The 'text-decoration' property on descendant elements cannot have any
>   effect on the decoration of the ancestor.

[text-decoration-skip](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-css3-text-20101005/#text-decoration-skip0), as mentioned in the linked question is supported by neither the latest version of Chrome, nor [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_CSS_support_chart)

---

I don't know if this is acceptable to you, but since the solution below doesn't work, this might be your only way to do it:

```
<span>
   <span class="strikethrough">Hello </span>
   <a href="#">World!</a>
</span>​

.strikethrough {
   text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

*It is valid to nest span elements.* [Are nested span tags OK in XHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078127/are-nested-span-tags-ok-in-xhtml)

---

**Doesn't work**:

The property will be inherited by the child by default. If you do not want that, override it.

```
span > a {
   text-decoration: none;
   /* or perhaps 
   text-decoration: underline;
   */
}
```

This will ensure all anchor elements that appear as a direct descendent of a span element will not have a strikethrough.

Comment: @ascii-lime: Indeed, hence the CSS comment.

Comment: @dunsmoreb: Oh, wow. It doesn't. Apparently the underline gets applied **in addition to** the strikethrough. I'm looking into other ways.

Comment: @xbonez: Sorry not acceptable. You have effectively done the same thing which I mentioned not to in my **Note** in question.

Comment: @TimTom: Fair enough. Hopefully someone comes along who can show a better way of achieving this.