# .filter() return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, get, jquery-data

I have a problem with `.filter()` for the data returned from `$.get()`.

```
$.get(url, function(data){
  $(data).filter('[ref=A]').html() // return undefined
});
```

HTML

```
<span ref='B'><span ref='A'>abc</span></span>
```

If I do

```
 $(data).filter('[ref=B]').html() // return <span ref='A'>abc</span>
```

After removing `<span ref="B">` and do

```
$(data).filter('[ref=A]').html()// return abc
```

My question is how can I get the HTML abc with tag `<span ref="B">`?

Did I use filter() incorrectly? Please advise.

Comment: For latecomers: nested spans seem incorrect but it turns out they are acceptable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078127/are-nested-span-tags-ok-in-xhtml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.filter` only applies to the outermost element.  You want to use `.find`.

Additionally, the last span tag is not closed.

Comment: @Till that's because `.data` *is* `[ref=B]`.  `.find` only works on descendants.

Comment: @Till it would help if we knew what you are trying to achieve.  What is the problem/desired solution in general?

Comment: I got your meaning...is it filter [ref=B] first then find??

Comment: My desired solution is, is there any way I only use one command to get [ref=A] in this situation??